# Database pattern for storing and querying few "Active" rows in large table of mostly "Inactive" data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008R2 table with millions of rows. Each row has an "Active" column (bit). At any given time, there may be dozens of "Active" records, and they will be the ones most recently added to the table (usually added in the last several seconds).

On the application side (C#) I have fairly high frequency polling of the table of the form "select * where active = 1". These rows are then updated frequently as they are processed through several processing stages. (a status field on the row goes from 1 through 10 for instance).

My concern is that having an index on the "Active" field is not all that helpful since the field is 99.99% "0" and the statistics are probably never getting updated, and the ones I care about are all at the "end" of the table anyway (there is an auto-increment primary key). Likewise updating the row based on PK might be slower then it needs to be since i know the updates are all happening to the rows at the end of the table.

Now I'm sure this can be improved upon. 
Would it be prudent to keep a copy of the active data in its own smaller table to improve queryability?

Would an indexed view or some other construct accomplish the same thing?

Should I instead be using a standing query of some kind to keep track of these rows, instead of polling the table?

Comment: I did see one related question, but his table had 20,000 rows and the answers were "don't bother"!

Comment: Create a *filtered* index using `where active = 1` if (most of) your queries always contain that condition. The columns for the index probably depend on what you usually retrieve from that table, but the PK is probably a good start.

Comment: I would look into partitioning the table.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx

Comment: Are you currently encountering performance problems with the "select * where active=1" query? I prefer the smaller table technique, however there will be some overhead. As "active" records are added, add the PK and status to the smaller table (directly or using a trigger). Poll the small table and remove record when status changes. I used a similar technique on a mysql table containing 64 million records. Small table was in-memory only. Performance was very good.

Comment: I like all 3 comments thanks ... i assumed there were sql server constructs to use that i was unfamiliar with ... perhaps filtered index and/or table partitioning is the key. I also like the idea of keeping the "Active" rows in memory ... i can re-create from the full table after a power failure or something ... i have not noticed particular performance problems so far but the more responsive the better for this app as i'm trying to turn around requests as soon as i can (users are waiting for them to complete)